# Efficiently using correct redis data types for specific cases

Tags: performance, types, redis, memory-efficient

Title: Efficiently using correct redis data types for specific cases.

I understand the primary 5 data types redis has to offer (and how they work) but knowing which to use in a specific case, regardless of how many tutorials I've read, is confusing to me!

For example, would I use `sadd` or `hincrby` for measuring a unique statistic thats dependendant upon a session/user-like ID.

My objective is to use redis as efficiently as possible while still providing all of the possible total(s) for statistics/analytics.

Example:

```
var device = {
    UDID: 1
};

redis.incr("total_app_visits"); // Is this wasted memory due to being able to total `unique_app_visits` and `returning_visits_total` below ?

// Alternatively we could use hincryby("unique_app_visits", device.UDID, 1);
// Which is more efficient here? Which would work better for getting the most out of?
redis.sadd("unique_app_visits", device.UDID,  function(err, result) {
    if (result === 0) { // If this is not a unique visit, then it means they are a returning customer.
        redis.hincrby("returning_app_visits", device.UDID, 1);
        redis.incr("returning_visits_total"); // Is this also wasted memory due to being able to get the total from `returning_app_visits` by iterating with `hgetall` Or is this a compuational performance cost too great?
    }
});
```

** Edit **
An example of using `hgetall` to retrieve the total for `returning_app_visits`:

```
redis.hgetall("returning_app_visits", function(err, result) {

    var returning_visits_total = 0;
    for (user in result) {
        returning_visits_total = returning_visits_total + Number(result[user]);
    }

    console.log("returning_visits_total: " + returning_visits_total);
});
```

Related resources: 
[What are the underlying data structures used for Redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625246/what-are-the-underlying-data-structures-used-for-redis) 
[Redis types and their respective pros and cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746677/redis-types-and-their-respective-pros-and-cons)

Comment: I can't give a simple answer to that. It all depends on the use case in question. I __can__ tell you that there's more to _"use redis as efficiently as possible"_ than just those 5 datatypes. For example, choosing when to apply Lua scripting and/or transactions. Also, storing your data as msgpack is very efficient memory-wise but can be a CPU tradeoff when you need this data in Lua. All in all, I think the scope of your question is too big.

Comment: I might add that in some scenarios an extremely efficient use of redis is possible: [__Bit and byte level operations__](http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization) . These very powerful solutions will be overlooked if you simplify all use cases with "_what redis data type should I use_".